# Teams Bot await notificationApp.notification.installations() is empty one out of 2 times

Tags: botframework, teams-toolkit

I am creating a Teams Notification Bot using the Teams Toolkit and a httpTrigger.  When deployed to production, the await notificationApp.notification.installations() is blank one out of 2 times.
As a result, I can send adaptive cards to users only sometimes. It is very inconsistent.